# Distribution of limit of empirical measures with noise

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence, large-deviation-theory

Suppose that we have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with probability distribution $\mu$ and define random empirical measures as

$$\mu_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{X_k}$$

We know these almost surely converge weakly to $\mu $ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$. Now suppose that $Y_1,Y_2,...$ is a sequence of independent standard $\mathbb{R}^2$ multivariate normal random variables independent of the sequence $X_1,X_2,...$ I am interested in the distribution of the measures that are the weak limits of the sequence defined as

$$\nu_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n (\delta_{X_k}+Y_k)$$

Would such a distribution even exist? Is the set of all outcomes where the weak limit does not exist a null set? Is this problem even well defined? If anyone has any sources on this, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\delta_x$ is defined on sets and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ is a number, then what is $\delta_x + y$?

Comment: Ah, I'm assuming OP means the convolution of $\delta_{X_k}$ and the distribution of $Y_k$, but possibly they had a different definition in mind?